# iterate over two lists and concatenate based on substring in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to iterate through two list and concatenate elements if the substring in list 2 `l2` match with elements in `l1` below. Can you help me with this?

```py
l1=['Rule1','Rule2','Rule3']
l2=['This is Rule1 for boys', 'That is Rule2', 'That is Rule1','This is not Rule', 'This is Rule3','Which is Rule3 for girls']
```

Expected Output:

```py
l2=['This is Rule1 for boys|Rule1', 'That is Rule2|Rule2', 'That is Rule1|Rule1','This is not Rule', 'This is Rule3|Rule3','Which is Rule3 for girls|Rule3']
```

Comment: (in regards to 'how you can improve your question')   
You ought to use proper [markdown syntax highlighting](https://support.codebasehq.com/articles/tips-tricks/syntax-highlighting-in-markdown) for the language you are using.   
The format for questions is generally [problem summary][attempt][expected behavior][unexpected behavior] and you should try to be as explicit as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.
It is not the most elegant way of doing it, but the algorithm is quite simple to understand this way.

```py
def fn(l1, l2):
    l3 = []
    for item in l2: 
        for substring in l1:
            if substring in item:
                l3.append(f"{item}|{substring}")
                break
        else: l3.append(item)
    return l3


l1=['Rule1','Rule2','Rule3']
l2=['This is Rule1 for boys', 'That is Rule2', 'That is Rule1','This is not Rule', 'This is Rule3','Which is Rule3 for girls']

print(fn(l1, l2))
# OUTPUTS:
# ['This is Rule1 for boys|Rule1', 'That is Rule2|Rule2', 'That is Rule1|Rule1', 'This is not Rule', 'This is Rule3|Rule3', 'Which is Rule3 for girls|Rule3']
```

Comment: The code can become "more elegant" with the use of the [`else` clause](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops). So you can remove the lines containing `foundSubstring = False` and `foundSubstring = True`, and replace `if not foundSubstring:` with a plain `else:`

Comment: @ruancomelli You cannot use an else clause. [for loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) iterate multiple times. If I used your suggestion, duplicate items would be appended.

Comment: Sorry, now that I reread my comment I noticed that I wasn't clear at all. I meant to use and `else` clause for the `for` loop (not for the `if`). Take a look at the reference I linked in the previous comment. An `else` clause for a loop statement is like saying "if no `break` statement was executed, then to this".